# Question only has 3 close votes in review queue

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

As most of us know, there has been a change to the close vote review queue. In that it is only showing the questions with 4 close votes now. However, this question only has 3. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4158395).

> [image]

---

To answer the comment stating that there is 1 close vote for "off topic" as well as the 3 "too broad" close votes. It only shows 3 here too.

> [image]

---

I just voted to close, and refreshed that question page and now it shows 4 close votes. So it only did have 3 close votes.

> [image]

Any explanation for why this is?

Comment: Why does the box up the top show "Should this question be closed as: too broad or **off-topic**"? (emphasis mine) - is there a "hidden" off-topic vote?

Comment: It has an off-topic vote but that is only shown if you go to the detail dialog of off-topic, if the off-topic reason is still an available option. (you won't see votes for Not a real question )

Comment: @rene And the reason it doesn't show up on the dialog is that it's using one of the old reasons that has since been removed.  The vote is still there, it just doesn't have anywhere to show it on the dialog.

Comment: @Servy I was ninja editing that comment but yes, that is it :-)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian from the sounds of it - it has three *current* close votes... The fourth looks to be an older *off-topic* reason

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Then perhaps the oldest vote aged out.

Comment: I've never really thought about it too much, but does that summary bar also take into account flags that people have that relate to close reasons... That could account for the off-topic? @Servy?

Comment: Shog9's proposal that was implemented did mention both close flags and close votes (and, in fact, showed that setting the threshold at 8 would have had 1 question in the queue).

Comment: @JonClements It does, but the "show only questions with 4 close votes" shouldn't take flags into account.

Comment: The queue is being cleared in *batches*, until *all batches* have completed you'll still see those questions in the queue.

Comment: @Wooble is correct here: that particular question had 3 votes and 2 *flags* on it when Lower saw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [m0sa's implementation answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223349/140890):

> Review tasks with less close votes and **no `do not close` review results will be gradually (performance...) removed** from the review queue.
>
> Expect the SO close vote review queue to start shrinking down to ~5k tasks

Emphasis mine. Questions are removed from the review queue in *batches* and until that process is completed you'll still see posts with fewer than 4 close votes in the queue. The queue is not yet down to ~5k, ergo, the process is not yet complete.

After the process completes, you'll still find posts in that queue that have 0 *do not close* counter votes; a post with 3 close votes and no *do not close* votes is perfectly at home.

For the specific post, someone could have voted to close it for any off-topic reason, and that vote has now been timed out or retracted. Caching still marks the question as having a 'off-topic` vote.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: removed the 'obsolete' part.

Comment: Also note that anything with a "do not close" review on it stays in the queue regardless of vote count.

Comment: @Shog9: further clarified, thanks.